# How to modify task_struct in Linux Kernel 3.8.0

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduling, smp

I am currently working on a project involving modifying the way linux priorities are implemented.

To do so I have :

- **a custom syscall** : That modifies the task_struct of a process to change its priority
- **modified kernel/sched/fair.c**
- **modified the standard task_struct to add new fields**

  While the custom syscall works : it gets correctly called and prints to dmesg the **fair.c** file doesn't seem to take into account the changes.

[original fair.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.8#L3833)

Changes to fair.c :

```
 /*
  * move_task - move a task from one runqueue to another runqueue.
  * Both runqueues must be locked.
  */
 static void move_task(struct task_struct *p, struct lb_env *env)
 {
         deactivate_task(env->src_rq, p, 0);
         if (p->prio_per_cpu)
         {            
            p->rt_priority = p->smp_prio[env->dst_cpu];
            printk(KERN_EMERG "We are in move_task function");
         }
         set_task_cpu(p, env->dst_cpu);
         activate_task(env->dst_rq, p, 0);
         check_preempt_curr(env->dst_rq, p, 0);
 }
```

p->prio_per_cpu is set to 1 in the syscall, but move_task function doesn't seem to see it.

The syscall :

```
/* system call to set the new field in 
 * task struct 'smp_prio' that allows 
 * one priority per processor on SMP machines
 */

asmlinkage long sys_set_smp_prio(pid_t pid, const char *smp_prio)
{
 struct pid *pid_struct;
 struct task_struct *p;

 pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
 p = pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID);
 p->prio_per_cpu = 1;
 p->smp_prio = (char*) smp_prio;
 printk(KERN_EMERG "SMP priorities are correctly set \n");
 return 1;
}
```

I get the syscall printk message.

The [original](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init_task.h?v=3.8#L150) task_struct

The modified task_struct :

```
#define INIT_TASK(tsk)  \
 {                                                                       \
     .state          = 0,                                            \
     .stack          = &init_thread_info,                            \
     .usage          = ATOMIC_INIT(2),                               \
     .flags          = PF_KTHREAD,                                   \
     .prio_per_cpu   = 0,                                            \
     .smp_prio       = NULL,                                         \
     .prio           = MAX_PRIO-20,                                  \
     .static_prio    = MAX_PRIO-20,                                  \
     .normal_prio    = MAX_PRIO-20,                                  \
     .policy         = SCHED_NORMAL,                                 \
     .cpus_allowed   = CPU_MASK_ALL,                                 \
     .nr_cpus_allowed= NR_CPUS,                                      \
     .mm             = NULL,                                         \
     .active_mm      = &init_mm,                                     \
     .se             = {                                             \
             .group_node     = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.se.group_node),    \
     },                                                              \
     .rt             = {                                             \
             .run_list       = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.rt.run_list),      \
             .time_slice     = RR_TIMESLICE,                         \
     },         
     [...]
```

When I modified move_task() to print a message unconditionally it did print that message.

I am sure 
    move_task
gets called with the task_struct argument of the thread modified by the syscall because I manually force thread migration by setting cpusets (bitmask) and move_task is the very bit of code that performs migration from one cpu to another.

Why aren't the changes done by the custom syscall not effective in the move_task() function ?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: First obvious question I think of is have you put a breakpoint at the line `if (p->prio_per_cpu)` to see what the value of `p->prio_per_cpu` is at the time of evaluation.  If it is `0`, it never gets to the print function.

Comment: What does `deactivate_task(env->src_rq, p, 0);` do to `p`?

Comment: Also, it looks like `p` is has local scope to `sys_set_smp_prio()`  True?

Comment: **deactivate_task** removes the task represented by p from the runqueue it is actually in

Comment: What are the changes made to task_struct ? Could you please post it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution a long time ago, but just for the record : I am testing this new kernel facilities with real-time threads. They aren't scheduled by the CFS scheduler (fair.c)

Comment: If you found a solution, do tell it - otherwise this has no value to anyone else and the question should rather be deleted.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear, the solution is in my post : real-time programs are not scheduled using fair.c hence move_task() not being called...

Answer (score 0):

The locally defined `struct task_struct *p;` in this function:

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_smp_prio(pid_t pid, const char *smp_prio)
{
 struct pid *pid_struct;
 struct task_struct *p;  //THIS COPY OF task_struct *p HAS NO CONNECTION...

 pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
 task = pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID);
 p->prio_per_cpu = 1;
 p->smp_prio = (char*) smp_prio;
 printk(KERN_EMERG "SMP priorities are correctly set \n");
 return 1;
}
```

Has no visible relationship to the argument passed `struct task_struct *p` (at least in the provided code)

```
static void move_task(struct task_struct *p, struct lb_env *env) //TO THIS ONE
 {
         deactivate_task(env->src_rq, p, 0);
         if (p->prio_per_cpu)  //If this value is zero, printk will never be called.
         {            
            p->rt_priority = p->smp_prio[env->dst_cpu];
            printk(KERN_EMERG "We are in move_task function");
         }
         set_task_cpu(p, env->dst_cpu);
         activate_task(env->dst_rq, p, 0);
         check_preempt_curr(env->dst_rq, p, 0);
 }
```

That is, I do not see where you are calling `move_task()` from within `sys_set_smp_prio()` with its updated value for `p->prio_per_cpu = 1;`.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: @rykker Sorry my fault, the code I posted was wrong I have just edited it. The code compiles properly.

Comment: So, your question is answered then?

Comment: I mean my code compiled properly which would not have been the case with an access to p->prio_per_cpu (would have segfaulted), it is just when copying the code on stackoverflow that there have been an error.

Comment: @MehdiSouihed What ryyker is pointing to is that the argument `p` in `move_task` might belong to a different task than the one whose `prio_per_cpu` field you are modifying in function `sys_set_smp_prio`. If you think otherwise, please print the PID inside `move_task` and cross check whether the PID of the task you modified in `sys_set_smp_prio` is also printed there.

Comment: @VivekS Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention that I have a test program that forces thread migration by pinning them consecutively on different cpus (cpu bitmask). I am sure that works because I can visualize it with `trace-cmd`  and `kernelshark`. `move_task()` has to be called during a thread migration from one cpu to another.